# Eclipse, Git pull to existing repository, where are new projects

Tags: eclipse, egit, pull, new-project

Using Eclipse 4.21 + Egit 2.20 on Linux, all components are up to date. The Eclipse workspace is linked to a local repository stored outside of the workspace folder. The remote repository is on GitHub.

After a pull (either made within Eclipse or outside using git cmdline), my friend and I can see each other updates or new files in existing projects. But each of us cannot see NEW project added by the other developer. The new project files are on GitHib and are actually saved in the local working folder after the git pull.

No matter how many times I refresh the package explorer view or exit/restart Eclipse. The new project doesn't show up in Eclipse package explorer. Each time, a manual "import existing project" is necessary.

Is it because I added .metadata is the .gitignore file at the root of the repository? More importantly, what is the recommended practice so that new project, deleted projects which are committed to the remote repository to sync automatically in Eclipse package explorer after a git pull?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it as it is designed to be used.  The concepts of the Eclipse Workspace and folders in your Git repository don't link that way automatically, just as creating a new directory in the workspace directory doesn't automatically make a new project show up in the UI.